# How to add custom text near category/tag title in Wordpress Twenty Fifteen Theme?

Tags: php, functions, archives

You can see the archive.php's title php code on twenty fifteen theme here:

```
<?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
            ?>
```

I would like to add some custom text after category/tag title. Can I do that with archive.php? How to do that?
In twenty fifteen theme both category and tag pages use archive.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, you should [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), so you can update the parent (Twenty Fifteen) without worries.

Looking at the [WordPress hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), you could copy the archive.php to the child theme and edit it, but would need to check what archive it is, of posts, custom post types, etc.

Instead, copy archive.php twice, rename one to category.php and one to tag.php. You could even use category-{slug}.php for specific categories (same goes for tags).

```
// in category.php / tag.php / ...
the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
_e('Some custom text','twentyfifteen-child');
the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
```